# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Redirecting to same page with culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have localization on my project. What I want is to whenever a user changes culture it redirects him to the same page he was in. But now with the new culture.

For example if the user is on the Register Page here's the link that appears:

```
http://localhost:49445/pt/Account/Register
```

with `pt` being the culture.

I started looking around and came up with this change culture method:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang)
{
    var langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", lang) { HttpOnly = true };
    Response.AppendCookie(langCookie);
    string url = this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work cause it's just gonna redirect me again to

```
http://localhost:49445/pt/Account/Register
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:49445/en/Account/Register
```

I've been looking around not finding anything. Can someone point me in the right direction? Or provide a good answer?

Answer (score 2):

the current culture must be a part of your routes:

Global.asax

```
const string defaultCulture = "sk";

routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultLocalized",
        "{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = defaultCulture },
        new { culture = "sk|cz" }
);
```

set current culture for each request:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {           
        SetCurrentCulture();
    }

    private void SetCurrentCulture()
    {
        var queryItems = Request.RawUrl.Split(new char [] {'/', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("sk-SK");

        HashSet<string> suportedLanguages = new HashSet<string>() { "sk", "cz" };

        var currentLang = string.Empty;

        if (queryItems.Length > 0)
            currentLang = queryItems[0].ToLowerInvariant();            

        if (suportedLanguages.Contains(currentLang))
        {
            if (currentLang == "cz")
            {
                currentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
            }                
        }            

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
    }
```

link for switching the cultures:

```
           <a href="@Url.ActionWithCurrentQuery(new { culture = "sk" })" title="Slovensky" class="m-xs right">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/slovak-flag.GIF")" alt="Slovensky" title="Slovensky"  />
            </a>
```

the action with current query generates html based on the current url but with different culture:

/en/Home/Action?param=1 becomes /de/Home/Action?param=1

```
public static string ActionWithCurrentQuery(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
        {
            var request = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, "http");
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            foreach (string key in request.QueryString.Keys)
            {
                query[key] = request[key];
            }
            var routeQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
            foreach (string key in routeQuery)
            {
                query[key] = routeQuery[key];
            }
            uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

            return uriBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I'll test this approach in a bit. Do you know if there is a way to redirect to the same page and keep validation messages. For example if the user tried to register but some error messages showed. And then you changed culture and it would redirect retaining the validations messages.

Comment: @Lokuzt validation messages are shown as a result for POST requests. If you change the route you make a new GET request thus the validation messages will disappear. You have to re-submit the form to show these messages again.

Comment: I've been trying to re-submit the form with tempdata. But I haven't been successful but still think that's not the right way. Do you have any clues to which approach I should take?

Comment: @Lokuzt Wouldn't be easier to set the right culture before the user starts filling up the registration form?

Answer (score 2):

To change only 1 parameter, such as the culture use the following helper:

```
public static string ActionWithNewCulture(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string culture)
{
    var newRouteData = new RouteValueDictionary(urlHelper.RequestContext.RouteData.Values);
    newRouteData["culture"] = culture;

    return urlHelper.RouteUrl(newRouteData);
}
```